# Why does my flex header collapse if I set a larger height value?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout with a scrollable grid area using overflow on the parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/riri78/cvghazqf/139/

It work while I have the height to `300px` on the grid. But if I set the grid to something a bit higher in height it squeezes and makes it shrink in to as small as it can be.

I can't really figure out why that is, shouldn't be overflown not matter what the height it has?

Showing a header with correct height
[image]

Showing a squeezed header
[image]

Comment: you could have a `min-height` for the header if you don't want it to shrink beyond a  certain point. The cool thing about flex is that you have so much control in terms of how your grid should behave. You can define the `flex-direction`, use shorthand for for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, i.e. `flex: 0 0 100%`, pair all that with min and max height/width properties and you can shape your grid into anything you want. With flex, working in `%` is powerful.

Comment: Could you please add your “*[mcve]*” code to the question - ideally as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548) - that way the code (and not the pictures of code) can be easily used to demonstrate and recreate your problem, leading to better solutions for you and more useful solutions for other future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fully master flexbox, I would suggest you take a look at these properties:

`flex-direction`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` and experiment with min/max value settings.

Flexbox might be powerful on its own, but it is even more powerful when paired with CSS media queries. When working with smaller viewport devices, such as mobile phones, it could come in handy to work with some pixel specifications for the `min` values (heights especially).

This could be a small example of what you are trying to achieve:

```css
#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 15%;
    max-height: 25%;
    background-color: red;
}

#main .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    min-height: 85%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

#main .container .left-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 15%;
    min-width: 15%;
    max-width: 15%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: green
}

#main .container .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 85%;
    min-width: 85%;
    max-width: 85%;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-menu"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I am working in percentages, which is relative to the viewport dimensions. This means that smaller the scale, the smaller the elements become.

Best way to tweak the scales we want at smaller viewport sizes is what I mentioned earlier. Make use of `min-height` and `min-width` with pixel value instead of percentages.

One of the great things with a flexbox layout, is that it is easy to make use of the best practice, "mobile first" apporach.

First write up your CSS so that your grid look appropriate for a minimum of viewport of 320px in width. Then use media queries with min-width specifications for the adjustments you might need at certain breakpoints.

Mobile viewport min-width: 320px to 767.98px.
Tablet viewport min-width: 768 to 991.98px.
Desktop viewport min-width: 992px and forward.

Once you play around more, you'll easily see where in detail you need pixel values, and where you need percentages. If you have Bootstrap incorporated, you have a built-in grid system available to you through classes, `.row` and `.col`. If you have Bootstrap, I would also suggest you use `rem` for general padding purposes.

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/full/mdrJZwz).